# mongoexport into TSV file

Tags: mongodb, csv, database

I would like to export a MongoDB collection straight into a tab-delimited txt file. I see stackoverflow posts, etc. saying this is possible but the Mongo docs as well as the utility itself seem to state that only JSON and CSV are supported. Is there a way to do TSV in Mongo or do I need to do a Regex or other conversion after exporting?

Comment: From the `mongoexport` manual: "Changed in version 3.0.0: mongoexport also removed support for writing data to tsv files with the --tsv option." I have no idea why they removed the TSV output option. Using `sed` or similar to convert after export is a bit unwieldy, especially if you have text fields with commas in.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunate that they removed it. I ended up using csvformat -T in Python to convert.

Comment: I hacked something in my free time for this: https://github.com/mannu1200/mongoexport-TSV Have tested it poorly, please free feel to create an issue if you find any fault.